# CloudKit record exists (added days ago), does not get returned by query but can be fetched by ID

Tags: cloudkit

I have a situation where a CloudKit record is not being returned by a query (and also doesn't appear in the CloudKit dashboard), but it exists when fetching it by it's ID.

*The record was added days ago, so it really should have been indexed.*

The `record ID` metadata index has always been set for the record type.

The query I use is fetching all records for a particular record type in a custom zone.

Strangely, when I search for the record in the dashboard and select it, the `record name` field is blank on the detail panel.

It's very peculiar, and very concerning!

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Could you add some more information like the code that you are using to query CloudKit and maybe a screenshot of the data in the dashboard?